# Genius invents omnipresent personal lie detector, saves society

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to recall a book that I read as a paperback somewhere in the 1995-2005 timeframe.

- Protagonist is a genius, exhibits some spectrum behaviors
- Protagonist's life is deeply affected when, as a child, his brother is kidnapped and murdered; possibly living in Concord, Massachusetts at the time
- Protagonist grows up fascinated with criminal forensics
- Protagonist creates <s>recording</s> **lie detector** technology <s>through which everyone's life is recorded 24x7 from their viewpoint</s>
- <s>Recording</s> **lie detection** becomes both mandatory and discoverable as evidence
- This <s>recording</s> **lie detector** technology revolutionizes criminal forensics and ushers in a golden age where crime drops precipitously

> Near the end of the book, the unscrupulous business partner of the protagonist threatens to blackmail protagonist with knowledge of a crime protagonist had committed years ago; protagonist chooses to murder the partner, taking advantage of a backdoor protagonist had left in the <s>recording</s> **lie detector** technology to allow it to be evaded.

Any help identifying the book would be greatly appreciated!

[**Edit**: Following @JoeL.'s correct answer, I corrected the question so as to not to be misleading for future searchers.  Mea culpa!]

Comment: The description reminds me of James Halperin's [*The Truth Machine,*](http://www.amazon.com/Truth-Machine-James-Halperin/dp/0345412885) although the tech there is an infallable lie detector.

Comment: @JoeL., that's exactly it.  I don't know how I confuzzled 'recording device' with 'lie detector', but that's definitely the story I was looking for.  Could you enter that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done and done. I'm surprised, but glad to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is James Halperin's 1996 thought experiment/novel [*The Truth Machine.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345412885)

from the Amazon link:

> It is the year 2004. Violent crime is the number one political issue
>   in America. Now, the Swift and Sure Anti-Crime Bill guarantees a
>   previously convicted violent criminal one fair trial, one quick
>   appeal, then immediate execution. To prevent abuse of the law, a
>   machine must be built that detects lies with 100 percent accuracy.
>
> Once perfected, the Truth Machine will change the face of the world.
>   Yet the race to finish the Truth Machine forces one man to commit a
>   shocking act of treachery, burdening him with a dark secret that
>   collides with everything he believes in. Now he must conceal the truth
>   from his own creation . . . or face his execution.